"正解であり不正解"? What does it mean?
ともかく彼が消えた五差路方面へと足を進める。
どの路地に入っても正解であり不正解。そんな奇妙な謎かけのように、色とりどりの光があたりを埋め尽くしている。
The character is chasing his enemy! he says "どの路地に入っても" no matter what road I enter but what does "正解であり不正解" mean? How can one thing be both correct and incorrect?

You appear to fully understand the Japanese here, so the question is more about the story of the work

Your text clearly says:

正解であり不正解...そんな奇妙な謎かけ
every path is both correct and incorrect...such a strange riddle

So 正解であり不正解 is an expression intentionally meant to confuse the reader.
You need to interpret the specific situation from the entire context. From what's written here alone, this person may be saying it's not like a typical game-like situation where incorrect paths light up red and correct paths blue, but this is merely a guess.
